# Nested Loops with IF Statment in CMD

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, cmd, nested

I am trying to download files using the command prompt.
This user @user4317867 helped me to write commands for loops. The command worked with just a flow of one season the command is:

```bash
for /L %i in (1,1,24) do curl -O "the URL of the file to download"
```

Now I want to download a movie series using that command but when it finishes with one season, e.g Season 1, the URL is:

```bash
for /L %i in (1,1,24) do curl -O "http://cdn3.movie.af/drive1/Movie/Series/Grimm-S2/live/Grimm-S01E01-720p-BluRay-Movie.af.mp4"
```

Now when it is done with the first season, the next season's URL is the same as the previous one with two differences which are the season's number and the episodes number. For example: `"http://cdn3.movie.af/drive1/Movie/Series/Grimm-S2/live/Grimm-S02E01-720p-BluRay-Movie.af.mp4"`

- Season `S01`: Episodes `E01`-`E24`
- Season `S02`: Episodes `E01`-`E25`
- Season `S03`: Episodes `E01`-`E30`

Any advice is appreciated.

```dos
for /L %i in (1,1,24) do curl -O "the URL of the file to download".
for /L %i in (1,1,24) do curl -O "http://cdn3.movie.af/drive1/Movie/Series/Grimm-S2/live/Grimm-S01E01-720p-BluRay-Movie.af.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you have not used the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) tag, here is a basic example of how you might do this using one:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "CURL=%SystemRoot%\System32\curl.exe"
Set "URI=http://cdn3.movie.af/drive1/Movie/Series/Grimm-S2/live/Grimm-%%%J-720p-BluRay-Movie.af.mp4"

For /L %%G In (101,1,103) Do (
    Set "$=%%G"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For %%H In (!$:~-2!) Do (
        EndLocal
        If %%H Equ 1 (
            For /L %%I In (101,1,124) Do (
                Set "_=%%I"
                SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                For %%J In (S%%HE!_:~-2!) Do (
                    EndLocal
                    %CURL% -O "%URI%"
                )
            )
        ) Else If %%H Equ 2 (
            For /L %%I In (101,1,125) Do (
                Set "_=%%I"
                SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                For %%J In (S%%HE!_:~-2!) Do (
                    EndLocal
                    %CURL% -O "%URI%"
                )
            )
        ) Else If %%H Equ 3 (
            For /L %%I In (101,1,130) Do (
                Set "_=%%I"
                SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                For %%J In (S%%HE!_:~-2!) Do (
                    EndLocal
                    %CURL% -O "%URI%"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

As you have not attempted the task yourself, I will not be including an explanation of what is happening etc. If you wish to know more, you should open a Command Prompt window, and use the help option, `/?` for each of the commands used.